# how to sort list of strings and numbers by numbers

Tags: python

I want to sort this list by numbers, but I do not know how. I want to sort parenthesses by numbers, but if i do list.sort, it sorts by keys.

```
list = [("Max", 25), ("Lisa", 10), ("Jacob", 34)]
list.sort()
print(list)
```

how can i do it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The `.sort()` method (and the `sorted()` function) [accept a `key=` parameter, the value of which is a function to use for getting the sorting criterion for a given item](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort).

If you want to sort the tuples (not "parentheses") by the second item, pass a function that returns the second item.

```
list.sort(key=lambda item: item[1])
```

Comment: Why not indicating that this is a duplicated question?